# retrieve specific range of rows in a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a table structure like (OrderID [uniqueidentifier], OrderDesciption [nvarchar]), I am using ADO.Net + C# + VSTS 2008 + SQL Server 2008. The table is big, and I want to let client give me two inputs, begin range index and end range index, and I will return specific rows of the table which is in the range (between begin range index and end range index).

For example, if the client inputs to me 50, 100, and I want to return the 50th row until the 100th row.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 15):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in TSQL (2005 onwards) to do this:

```
SELECT  ID, Foo, Bar
FROM     (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row,
          ID, Foo, Bar
FROM    SomeTable) tmp
WHERE   Row >= 50 AND Row <= 100
```

Or with LINQ-to-SQL etc:

```
var qry = ctx.Table.Skip(50).Take(50); // or similar
```

Comment: Something wrong output from SQL Server management studio. I tried your SQL Statement in this way,
select [OrderStatus].[OrderID], [OrderStatus].[OrderStatus]
from
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row,
[OrderStatus].[OrderID], [OrderStatus].[OrderStatus] from [OrderStatus])
where Row >= 0 and Row < 100
Error message is,
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Where is your fix? I am confused. Could you point it out please? :-)

Comment: I have added a new column called OrderCreateTime, and I think if we SELECT xxx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderCreateTime) should be better than order by order by order ID, correct? And why?

Comment: tmp? I did not see in your current post, there is a term called "tmp"? Confused. :-)

Comment: If OrderID is an IDENTITY column, it will likely be increasing with time anyway, and is a simpler data type. Of course, if you have a clustered index on OrderCreateTime then it is ideal for ordering...

Comment: see "FROM SomeTable) tmp" - this alias is all that is required to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Marc, since OrderID is GUID and it is already a clustered index (because clients will frequently query order information by order ID), so do you think create a normal index on OrderCreateTime is an acceptable solution?

Comment: A Guid usually makes a very poor *clustered* index (but an excellent non-clustered index). Are you using "combing" to generate increasing guids? If not, I would recommend switching the clustered index to OrderCreateTime. A non-clustered index is also good at sorting - but just not **as** good, so if needs be, a non-clustered index on OrderCreateTime would do - but you are rarely doing equality matches on things that involve time, so *generally* times make a poor non-clustered index.

Comment: Is it possible to order such a table? I've created a table which contains a _DateTime_ column and I want to order on this column but apparently he "ignores" the ORDER BY.

Comment: This is my query but it doesn't order it on [eventdate]: SELECT
    [ID]
      ,[operation]
      ,[reason]
      ,[eventdate]
 FROM 
  (
   SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row,
    [ID]
      ,[operation]
      ,[reason]
      ,[eventdate]
   FROM 
    myTable
  ) tmp
 WHERE
  Row >= @rowFrom AND Row < @rowTo
 ORDER BY 
  eventdate DESC;

Comment: @thomasvdb look at the `OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)`.... presumably you need to tweak that?

Comment: Anyone have any stats on which solution is more efficient, this one or the one posted by @marc_s?

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti if you mean comparing the 2 SQL versions, then they have identical query plans; they perform the same

Answer (score 4):

Basically, your best bet in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 is a CTE - Common Table Expression - with a ROW_NUMBER() function in it - something like this:

```
WITH MyOrders AS
(
  SELECT
    OrderID,
    OrderDescription,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) as 'RowNum'
  FROM YourOrders
)
SELECT * FROM MyOrders
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

But this requires a useful and suitable `ORDER BY` clause, and ordering by a GUID is really not a good idea. DATETIME or an ever-increasing ID would be best.

Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry for my bad description, I do not want to let client specify range by the value of a GUID orderID, but specify range by the physical row number of the table. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Well, my CTE above in my post does this - it's just that selecting by a GUID is a really bad way of ordering your data - it's basically just totally random...... but if that's what you're looking for, my code snippet should achieve this.

Comment: Confused about this statement -- "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) as 'RowNum'" -- as orderID is random GUID, I want to retrieve range by physical row range in database table, not by the range of value of order ID. Looks like from the statement I quoted you select row range by orderID?

Comment: I agree Marc, but your statement has some error when executing in SQL Server management studio, I have posted my SQL code executing and output error message, what is wrong?

Comment: I have added a new column called OrderCreateTime, and I think if we SELECT xxx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderCreateTime) should be better than order by order by order ID, correct? And why?

Comment: @George2: yes, selecting by OrderCreateTime would be much better - since it defines a real order - by date/time the order was created. The GUID for Order ID is just a random number which really doesn't have an ordering characteristic.

Comment: The "ROW_NUMBER()" function must be defined over an ordering definition. Only when you put all your rows into an ORDER (of any kind), only then can you attach a ROW_NUMBER to them. A SQL Server row set per se doesn't have any order - that's why you have to define an order by issuing a OVER (ORDER BY (column name)) in order for the ROW_NUMBER function to know how to attach row numbers to rows.

Comment: Since OrderID is GUID and it is already a clustered index (because clients will frequently query order information by order ID), so do you think create a normal index on OrderCreateTime is an acceptable solution?

Comment: Thanks! A further question, do you think using CTE is better for my scenario or using plain T-SQL like Kiewic suggests is better? And why?

Comment: I can only second Marc Gravell's recommendation: GUID's make for very poorly performing CLUSTERED indices - it would be MUCH BETTER to have an "OrderID INT IDENTITY" and put the CLUSTERED Index on this column.

Comment: In the end, the execution plan for Kiewic's query and mine are identical. I prefer the CTE - it seems clearer to me - but that's a subjective, personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, the result will be ordered by **OrderID** column. Change **MyTable** with your table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) AS row FROM MyTable) a 
WHERE row > 50 AND row <= 100
```

The selected rows are from **50** to **100**, but notice that the 50th row is not included in the result.

Comment: I execute your statement but something from SQL Server Management Studio.

select *
from
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OrderStatus].[OrderID]) AS Row from [OrderStatus])
where Row >= 0 and Row < 100

Error message is,

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Hey, your erase the letter **a** that was after the **SELECT** on the third line. It's an alias and it is necessary.

Comment: I have added a new column called OrderCreateTime, and I think if we SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderCreateTime) should be better than order by order by order ID, correct and why?

Comment: The "a" gives a name to the anonymous query inside the parenthesis.

Comment: @maydenec This is equivalent to 

"SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 50, 50" 

in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) as row FROM Orders) a WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10

Comment: I have tried your solution, but something wrong, 

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrderStatus]
 (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [OrderID]) as row FROM [dbo].[OrderStatus]) 
 where row > 0 and row < 100

Error messages are,

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I have added a new column called OrderCreateTime, and I think if we SELECT xxx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderCreateTime) should be better than order by order by order ID, correct? And why?

Comment: you've missed naming the select ".. from Orders) >>a<< where.."