# Using an sql statement select next 4 items

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to select the next 4 items in a sql query. I have a sql query populating an asp repeater and its using a "select top 4 from ....." sql query. I want a button to select the next 4 from the database. Is this possible? Thanks all.

Comment: Suggest you show your data access code and query. What's your RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID, Foo, Bar
FROM     (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row,
          ID, Foo, Bar
FROM    SomeTable) tmp
WHERE   Row >= @RowRangeStart AND Row <= @RowRangeEnd
```

[retrieve specific range of rows in a SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023841/retrieve-specific-range-of-rows-in-a-sql-server-table)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at:

[How to: Return or Skip Elements in a Sequence (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx)

> Use the Take operator to return a given number of elements in
>   a sequence and then skip over the remainder.
>
> Use the Skip operator to skip over a given number of elements
>   in a sequence and then return the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way would be:

```
SELECT TOP 4 (fields)
WHERE idfield > (highest id field from last top 4 you selected)
```

Comment: You probably should.  I'm assuming his query has an `ORDER` since he's using `TOP`.

Comment: `Ass` `u` `me`?  Sorry, I can't help myself today;)