# PageIndexChanging Without Binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have `datagridview` linked with `dataSource`, this data source get data from table has 9 Million record and I'm searching in this table by name, after Binding data when need to change `PageIndex` this requires to research in 9 million records by this code:

Any method to change `PageIndex` without binding it again?

```
Protected Sub GVCenteralSearch_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GVCenteralSearch.PageIndexChanging
    GVCenteralSearch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GVCenteralSearch.DataSource = CentralSearch_DS
    GVCenteralSearch.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Notes : This Is Based on WebApp (ASP.net)

Comment: Please elaborate on the question. what's `e`? Where is this code? WebApp is what? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  You do have a few options though, you can cache the data so you don't have to get it from the database again.  You could also look into javascript alternative to paging the data (jQuery DataTable plugin).  Alternatively you can re-write the query to only grab the records you need.  This would still take the round trip to get the data displayed, but it won't be as significant.

Comment: Can you give me Example Plz ?

Comment: [Caching sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831665/how-to-store-datatable-in-cache-to-reuse-it)                 [Jquery DataTable](http://datatables.net/).              [SQL retrieving specific rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023841/retrieve-specific-range-of-rows-in-a-sql-server-table)