# Paging in rss feed on a web-form

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

I have a RSS-feed in my web-app. It is shown 5 recent news from the DB, using this query:

```
  SELECT TOP 5 newsID, Title, Date, Description FROM News ORDER BY Date DESC
```

How can I provide user a list, below all this news, where user would be ablle to choose another 5 news, by pressing page 2, another by pressing page 3 and e.t.c.?
Not the best explanation here. I mean, like in GridView, to set the Paging ability.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking how to get a specific range of rows from a sqlserver query, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023841/retrieve-specific-range-of-rows-in-a-sql-server-table). else, you will need to show your code, explain your problem and tell what you've tried.