# How to select top 5 after 20 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select top 5 * from tbl_post ORDER BY Id DESC
```

I want to select the first 5 rows after the 20th row. How I can do this?

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieve specific range of rows in a SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023841/retrieve-specific-range-of-rows-in-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: Actually, this is a  Azure SQL Database.
So I think it is a 2014, or maybe 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use OFFSET and FETCH [MSDN OFFSET FETCH Clause](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_post ORDER BY whatever OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Note that you have to order by something for this to work, and you cannot use `top` at the same time

Answer (score 2):

```
with x as (select row_number() over(order by id desc) as rn, * from tbl_post)
select t.* 
from x join tbl_post t on x.id = t.id
where x.rn between 20 and 25
```

This is the easiest way to assign row numbers and selecting the rows you need later on.

Comment: The code was correct before the edit, now it's just more complicated :-)

Comment: this is because values from only `tbl_post` table were required

Comment: @dnoeth.. i would have had the question mentioned the column names

Comment: If your crystal ball is broken you might expect the OP to select the columns he actually needs :-))

Answer (score 0):

Use OFFSET and LIMIT

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     tbl_post 
ORDER BY id DESC offset 100 limit 5;
```